# Смена рекламного объявления AdSense при входе с мобильного устройства

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, всех с Наступающим! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы обявление AdSense, менялось на другое (для мобильных устройств) при входе с мобильного устройства, и чтобы основное объявление, при ненадобности его замены, удалялось.

Answer (score 1):

1. Коды AdSense для мобильного и обычного в отдельные файлы.
2. Есть такое понятие как UserAgent браузера. Смотрите на него, определяете, что за браузер, и, соответственно загружаете соответствующий файл с AdSense кодом.
3. Можно, как вариант, с помощью JavaScript, определять расширение экрана. Исходя из этого подставлять нужный файл. Я так понял, Вам важно, чтобы реклама не вылазила за рамки моб. устройства, поэтому этот вариант самый приемлемый, потому что зная размеры рекламы, Ваш код должен определять, поместится ли он в рамки браузера или нет.